# Media content not show when DEBUG is False on IIS

Tags: python-3.x, django, iis, iis-10

I want run my django3.2 project on IIS v10 and I have a problem when I change Debug from True to False!
Until DEBUG=True, everything working very well but when I change it to "False", MEDIA content not show!

*settings.py:*

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "statics",
]
```

Comment: Please add more error details in your post.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.